# Como obtener un dato de una promesa con react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Estoy tratando de hacer una petición get a un api que me devuelve una promesa con isomorphic fetch . Los datos los obtengo bien pero no me los muestra en la página, es decir no me renderiza el resultado seguramente porque no estoy accediendo bien a la promesa devuelta. El archivo que me hace el GET es el siguiente:

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

const endpoint = 'https://api.xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

const api = {
  hacienda: {
    async read(id = null) {
      try {
        if (!id) {
          const response = await fetch(endpoint);
          const data = await response.json();
          console.log(Promise.resolve(data.nombre));
          return Promise.resolve(data);
        }
        const response = await fetch(`${endpoint}/${id}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(Promise.resolve(data.nombre));
        return Promise.resolve(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(Promise.resolve(error));
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    }



  }
};

export default api;
```

En otro archivo aparte tengo el action que exporta la acción y en el reducer tengo lo siguiente :

```
import api from '../fecth/api'

const apiReducer=(state='Vacío',action)=>{

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'APIGET':
            return api.hacienda.read();
            break;

        default:
            return state;
            break;
    }
}


export default apiReducer;
```

Y por último en la App tengo esto:

```
function App() {

  const counter=useSelector(state=>state.counter);

  const logged=useSelector(state=>state.login);

  const api=useSelector(state=>state.getApi);

  const dispatch=useDispatch();

  return (

    <div className="App">

  <h1>Counter {counter}</h1>
  <button onClick={()=>dispatch(increment(5))}>+</button>
  <button onClick={()=>dispatch(decrement())}>-</button>
    <h1>Logged= {logged?<h2>Logueado</h2>:'False'}</h1>


<button onClick={()=>dispatch(getApi())}>Api</button>
  <h1>Api= {api}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Como verán puse un console.log(Promise.resolve(data.nombre)); el cual me muestra el dato el cual esta correcto . La promesa devuelta es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo lo estoy intentando renderizar  de esta forma :

```
<h1>Api= {api}</h1>
```

Sin embargo eso no me renderiza nada, solamente me lo muestra en la consola.

Comment: Llamadas asincronas no deben hacerse en el reducer. Intenta usar redux-thunk o redux-saga

Comment: Correcto ese middleware era lo que ocupaba . Excelente